# ALSA behaviour on stereo mic during process suspend

Tags: audio, alsa

**Goal**

- Suspend a Python process listening to `pcm.record_right` (for Google-Assistant)
- Continue using `pcm.record_left` in a different python process (for [Snowboy hotword](https://snowboy.kitt.ai/) detection)

**Use Case**

- I want to use Snowboy to detect a hotword and then pass further voice interaction over to Google Assistant.  Once the conversation finishes, I want to disable Google Assistant until I request it from Snowboy again.
- I'm working with the Google-Assistant Library SDK and want to ensure that it is not listening, unless I permit it!  (So using the SDK's mic-mute command isn't enough.)
- I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and an external USB stereo mic (Blue Snowball).
- The reason that I want to suspend and un-suspend the Assistant process is that if I stop and start the program entirely, it takes too long (between when Snowboy detects the hotword and when the Assistant is ready).

**What I've Tried**

- I've used the `.asoundrc` settings below.  When I suspend the Assistant process (accessing the right mic), I run `arecord` using `record_left`, but get the error below.  For testing purposes, I use `kill -STOP <pid>` and `kill -CONT <pid>`.
- I also tried sharing the mic (using dsnoop) without separating the left and right channels, but got the same error.
- I've also tried to trace where Google's SDK disables the mic, but their sample Python code loads a shared object called `libassistant_embedder.so` which [is not open-source](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/209#issuecomment-374690871).

**Questions**

- Is it possible to suspend a linux process that is using an ALSA device and still leave the device available?
- If not, does anyone know if JACK-Audio might be able to do this?
- Any other approaches that might work?

**Error**

ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave arecord: main:788: audio open error: Device or resource busy

**Contents of ~/.asoundrc**

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  capture.pcm "mic"
  playback.pcm "speaker"
}
pcm.mic {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
  }
}
pcm.speaker {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:0,0"
  }
}
# see: https://alsa.opensrc.org/Dsnoop, section 1.2.3
pcm.record_left {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 234884
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1,0"
        channels 2
        rate 48000
    }
    bindings.0  0  #pick one of the stereo mic channels
}
pcm.record_right {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 2241234
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1,0"
        channels 2
        rate 48000
    }    
    bindings.0  1  #pick the other of the stereo mic channels
}
```

Comment: Not sure if ALSA can do that. Is Pulseaudio an option? It decouples transport from the sources/sinks, so use a Pulseaudio module to create two sources for right and left. Then you can suspend applications reading from one source, while applications reading from the other source continue.

Comment: Thanks @dirkt, I'm open to all options.  Reading up on Pulseaudio now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if ALSA can do that.

Is Pulseaudio an option? It decouples transport from the sources/sinks, so use a Pulseaudio module to create two sources for right and left. Then you can suspend applications reading from one source, while applications reading from the other source continue.

You'll need two [module-remap-source](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index13h3]). Use `pacmd` or `pactrl` to make them. Play around until it works (remove them first with `unload-module` if you want to change anything), then put it into the Pulseaudio configuration files. Use `pavucontrol` to get an idea what sources/sinks you have, and what applications are using them, and to set volumes.

Comment: Thanks for the compass headings @dirkt!  I got pulseaudio installed and played with a few `pacmd` commands.  Slow going since day-job keeps me busy on other things, but I'll keep at PA and report back.

Comment: Hi @dirkt, thanks again. I got this working with pulseaudio. I was able to get two processes to connect to the default pulse-audio mic source using .asoundrc with 

```pcm.!default pulse
ctl.!default pulse```

I didn't even have to separate the left and right channels nor use the `module-remap-source` since pulseaudio didn't complain when one of the connected processes was suspended.

Comment: That's even simpler. :-)